# Processing an InputStream to OutputStream on the fly through a HttpServlet

Tags: servlets, input, pipeline, on-the-fly

I'm trying to process a large text file through a HttpServlet (tomcat).

As this file can be large and the process should be very fast, I don't want to upload the file on the server and I've used the method `HttpRequest.getInputStream` to process the input on the fly. For example, I want to transform the input to upper-case with the code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EchoServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
        {
        OutputStream out=null;
        InputStream in=req.getInputStream();
        if(in==null) throw new IOException("input is null");
        try
            {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            out=resp.getOutputStream();
            int c;
            while((c=in.read())!=-1)
                {
                out.write((char)Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
        catch(IOException err)
            {
            //ignore
            }
        finally
            {
            if(out!=null) out.flush();
            if(out!=null) out.close();
            in.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I invoked my servlet with CURL:

```
curl -s -d @big.file.txt  "http://localhost:8080/test/toupper"
```

1) processing the input on the fly through a servlet, is it a good/common practice ?

2) my code seems to remove the carriage return ('\n') . Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1) processing the input on the fly through a servlet, is it a good/common practice ?*

Depends on the functional requirement. I would personally have used a servlet which accepts HTTP `multipart/form-data` requests instead of raw request bodies. This way it's reuseable on normal HTML forms.

> *2) my code seems to remove the carriage return ('\n') . Why ?*

The given code example doesn't do that. Maybe you've oversimplified it and you was originally using `BufferedReader#readLine()` while not using `PrintWriter#println()`. The `readLine()` indeed eats CRLFs.

There are more issues/inefficiencies in the given code snippet as well, but I can't give a decent answer on that as you seem not to *actually* be running the code as you posted in the question.

Comment: "my code doesn't do that", yes, but the '\n' have been removed in the output of curl. I've just removed the name of the package from my code.

Comment: I had a look at http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html after I read your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your servlet code locally (although using `java.net.URLConnection` instead of curl) and newlines are just preserved.